# how to make python print the whole file instead of just the single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, missing-data, readlines

I have a .csv file that has just one column of numbers and I want to read each number in the column and print it in the console like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

here is the code that I have used:

```
file_reference2 = open("file1.csv", "r")
read_lines1 = file_reference1.readlines()
for line1 in read_lines1:
    print(line1)

file_reference1.close()
```

what I expect is:

```
1
2
3
```

in the console.

But what I get is:

```
1
```

And the program stops. How do I make it print the whole file?

Comment: Where's your `file_reference1` defined? Or is that a typo?

Comment: Why do you not expect it to print `4`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It seems like a typo since your assigning `open` to `file_reference2`, but you're using `file_reference1`.

Comment: Things I usually do when posting about parsing a file are; 0) narrow the problem down to the smallest amount of code and data where the issue is still reproducible, 1) Python version, `python --version` 2) show all or part of file, `cat /path/to/file` 3) show all of code, `cat /path/to/script.py`, 4) show output of running the code on the CLI. This will make it easier to understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You create a variable `file_reference2`, but later call `file_reference1.readlines()` (notice the difference in variable names). You are probably reading lines from a wrong file as this code works well for me if I change that line to `file_reference2.readlines()` like this:

```
file_reference2 = open("file1.csv", "r") 
read_lines1 = file_reference2.readlines() 
for line1 in read_lines1: 
    print(line1)

file_reference2.close()
```